# Windows : How to protect process from getting killed in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, windows, dll

Is there any "GODLY" method through which i can protect my process from getting killed from:
 1>Task manager 2>Command prompt -- forcefully kill

Things i tried : 1. Hooking Open Process and Terminate Process

Result i got: well not much ,  i could only protect it from task manager but it gets killed through command prompt task kill command

Comment: Don't know or judge about your deeds, but I really hope there is none.

Comment: This is only for the project i'm working on. I don't want anyone to  terminate my process..I hope you have notice u can't kill mcafee mcshield.exe..Its the same thing i want to achieve

Comment: Yes I know (with have them on our employers boxes). You should prevent your processes from being killed by "permissions" (i.e. having them run with as the appropriate user). It is totally _annoying_ if you cannot kill an amok process on your own system.

Comment: Don't know the exact answer, but it lies somewhere in handling `WM_CLOSE` without being killed and `Terminate Process`

Comment: You might want to read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/22/191123.aspx).

Comment: thanks christian but i guess that is no help.. let me give you small idea what im trying to achieve and till now what i have achieved ... I want to protect a Service from getting stopped by any user ..well u can protect a service by adding security descriptor to it by using "SetServiceObjectSecurity" but that alone is not enough..

Comment: from task manager under service tab if u select a service right clicked it and then select "go to process" it will direct under process tab to the respective process if u kill that process service gets stopped..so in such case "Setservceobjec is not much of use..hence to protect that process i'm using "setwindowsHookex" and implementing hook to the "Openprocess" and "Terminate Process" and now i'm able to protect process from getting killed even when admin is trying to killed.. but it is only getting killed when i try to kill the same process from cmd prompt with admin privilege forcefully..

Comment: The proper solution is to not give admin access to anybody who might misuse it in such a way.  The "other" solutions, as often used by AV for example, require kernel mode code, and IIRC you have to either use unsupported methods or have a contract with MS to use their special AV interfaces.  One simpler approach is to use RtlSetProcessIsCritical, see http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43405/Protecting-Your-Process-with-RtlSetProcessIsCriti

Answer (score 0):

It is not too difficult to modify a process so it cannot be terminated by any other user than an administrator.

Look into:
GetKernelObjectSecurity
SetKernelObjectSecurity

In short: Obtain the security descriptor of the process to be protected, modify its DACL and write it back. Users that you deny access this way get an "Access denied" when trying to kill the process.

Comment: a short summary of each of the 'look into' things would be handy; linking them to official docs / good introductory articles would be better